# Find and display occurrence of one value from one column which belongs to value in another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as shown below.
Here value in column `WIRE` belongs to multiple `MODULES`.
For example `"134A-134A"` has multiple entries in column `WIRE`, but `MODULES` for that wire have different values.

[image]

[image]

So I am trying to get a view in which I will be able to see for one `WIRE` which all `MODULE` are there.

Hope I make it clear. Thanks.

in `MODULE`, there are 169 unique entries and in `WIRE` 3k unique entries.
but entire table has around 100K entries mix of diff combination of wire and module
now I want to see particular wire is present in how many modules and which are those(and I want to do this for all 3k entries... so I am trying to achieve this in a single query).

I want to see the `WIRE`which has a distinct `MODULE`,

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images to display data. Use the minimum amount of data to represent the problem and show it as formatted text.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Please also show your expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the requirement.

Do you want the `modules` for which no other `wire` is mapped?

```
SELECT T.*
  FROM YOUR_TABLE T
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT 1 FROM YOUR_TABLE TT
         WHERE TT.MODULE = T.MODULE
           AND TT.WIRE <> T.WIRE)
   AND T.WIRE = '134A-134A';
```

**-- Update**

According to your requirement, it seems like you just want the ordering and conditional value as follows:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN WIRE END AS WIRE, <ALL OTHER COLUMNS>
 FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.WIRE ORDER BY MODULE) AS RN,
              T.WIRE, <ALL OTHER COLUMNS YOU WANT>
         FROM YOUR_TABLE T) T
ORDER BY T.WIRE, T.RN
```

Comment: I want to see the result like in the picture. for one wire how many unique modules are there